# How to prevent DoubleColumnNavigationView from being collapsed under ipad

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

```swift
struct NavigationViewPadTest: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(0..<30){ i in
                Text("id:\(i)")
            }
            Text("abc")
            
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Use the above code to create a navigationView with a collapsible button at the top left of the screen. I don't want the navigationView to be collapsed and keep the DoubleColumn state. Is there a way to disable this button.
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The possible solution is to remove bar

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        List(0..<30){ i in
            Text("id:\(i)")
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)    // << here !!

        Text("abc")
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
}
```

Comment: It is indeed possible to disable folding by removing the bar. I'm still looking for other solutions because I still need to add other baritem in the left column. Thank you

Comment: It is possible to add just HStack with buttons above List, make it opaque if needed, and you'll have top-bar.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution. `DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle` is deprecated. Now you can use `NavigationSplitView`. If you want to prevent `NavigationSplitView` from being collapsed under iPad, you can try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var columnVisibility =
    NavigationSplitViewVisibility.doubleColumn
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility){
            List(0..<30){ i in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Details of \(i)")) {
                    Text("id:\(i)")
                }

            } .navigationBarHidden(true)

        } detail: {
            Text("Choose an item from the content")
            
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced) // this
    }
}
```